# doctrine strategy pattern

Tags: design-patterns, doctrine-orm, mapping

I am trying to create the following structure

```
class bot
{
    protected $name;
    protected $type;

    public function __construct($name, IBotType $type)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->type->produceProduct();
    }
}


class botType1 implements IBotType
{

    public function produceProduct()
    {
        return 'Donut';
    }
}

class botType2 implements IBotType
{

    public function produceProduct()
    {
        return 'Coffee';
    }
}
```

the only class that is an entity is the bot class, the types will have some basic configuration like name etc and some logic ex botType1 will be able to produce donuts and botType2 will produce coffee etc.

The main question is how can I store that information using doctrine and on loading the object from the database to create create the correct bot type.

I hope that makes sense!

Please note that I do not want to store each type into the database, I want to have a php class that I will store all the control logic in there.

(in the real application there is a collection of 100s of various bot types and we go through them and call getProducts in order to create the products etc, hope the above example make sense!)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time but I believe using the following article I should be able to so exactly what I asked form:
[strategy pattern cookbook](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/strategy-cookbook-introduction.html) or 
[decorator pattern cookbook](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/decorator-pattern.html)

have fun!